# Play lottie animation on button click flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I have the following widgets rendered.

[image]

The cup in the middle is a lottie animation that can be found [here](https://lottiefiles.com/8896-water-animation).
I am using the following package to show the lottie animation (It seemed to be the standard one) [pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)

In my code my lottie file is loaded as follows.

```
Lottie.asset("assets/animations/water.json",
                      height: 120, repeat: false),
```

What I want to achieve is when the plus button is clicked that the lottie file would play for one iteration.
When the minus button is clicked it would play one iteration in reverse. (I know there is a reverse property so this one I can achieve if I can figure out how to get it to work in one direction)
I tried creating an animation controller, but I have little to no experience working with it, and the following did not do anything.

```
RawMaterialButton(
     onPressed: () {
         _controller.forward();
         _changeWaterIntake(-1);
          },
     elevation: 2.0,
     child: Image.asset(
     "assets/images/subtract.png",
     height: 55,
     ),
shape: CircleBorder(),
                      ),
```

Any help or assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are few steps you can do to control your lottie animation:

**Step 1 :
Use TickerProviderStateMixin in your State for your animation controller. simply using**
with **:**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin
```

**Step 2 :
Declare and initialize your animation controller:**

```
 AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }
```

Your can change duration, add curves according to your need here above.

**Step 3 : Main Task :
Bind your Animation controller with the lottie animation and turn repeat as false.**

```
Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: Lottie.asset(
                'assets/watermation.json',
                controller: _animationController,
                height: 180,
                repeat: false,
              ),
            ),
```

**Step 4: The fun part simply use _animationController to play with your animation:**

```
  GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.forward();
              },
              child: Text('add'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.reverse();
              },
              child: Text('minus'),
            ),
```

**Full State Code:**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: Lottie.asset(
                'assets/watermation.json',
                controller: _animationController,
                height: 180,
                repeat: false,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.forward();
              },
              child: Text('add'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.reverse();
              },
              child: Text('minus'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }}
```

So you can dig into the documentation and learn about animations. You can similarly manipulate Lottie files and add amazing animations with them.

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve

Comment: totally wrong .....

Comment: please try to edit or update the answer @NicholasJela would help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Krish comment doesnt work for me, but i have slight changes to work

Instead of:

```
  GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.forward();
              },
              child: Text('add'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.reverse();
              },
              child: Text('minus'),
            ),
```

Use:

```
  GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.forward();
                                       _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
             },
              child: Text('add'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animationController.reverse();
              },
              child: Text('minus'),
            ),
```